# Charge car battery with lab bench power supply

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging

Is it possible to charge a lead acid car battery with a lab bench power supply?

I am thinking of hooking it up to 13.8 Volts and 1 Amps. Will this work?

Comment: Sounds good to me but 14.2 is used on flooded cells in cars to desulphate more. But 13.8 is good for float  . keep in mind a low Battery will demand as much current as you can supply so overcurrent needs to be gracefully protected. ( by its design). You can make it graceful by current limiting with a 30W headlamp in series

Comment: 14.4 V to fully charge it at room temperature. 14.6 V for some gel and AGM types. Just don’t leave it at extended times at that high voltage.

Comment: If your power supply has CC limiting you have no problems, simply set the voltage then connect the supply. If your supply has foldback current limiting, then you need to measure the current and slowly increase the voltage of the powers supply. If you place some resistance in series, then you'll never get close to your current without constant voltage adjustment.

Comment: Just a note to *not* do this indoors. Lead-acid batteries give off hydrogen gas while charging, which can be explosive.

Comment: Legit, purpose built (with safety features, maintenance float, etc) lead acid battery chargers are available for about $15.  Why mess around?

Comment: @KyleB perhaps because you need to charge it *now*, not when the shops are open/when you can get one delivered.  I've had to top up a small Li-ion pack (bike light - I wouldn't have got home in one piece without it) in the lab before - V limit set to about 60% of full charge voltage and a current of 0.25C (IIRC) was enough for one journey and meant I could avoid the need for a precise cutoff

Comment: @ChrisH Yeah except that's not what the OP was doing.  In an emergency, an EE with understanding of charging methods could pull it off.   OP wants something that he can use repeatedly.  Yours was a one-off instance.   One can find a counter example to almost anything.   My statement covers 99.7% of cases.  Why reinvent the wheel when you can buy one that's known safe and preengineered to charge batteries w/o chance of damaging them for the cost of a decent sandwich?

Comment: @KyleB the Q is rather lacking in detail, and I didn't read it the same as you, but I guess it doesn't matter any more

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75: Lab power supply has CC and CV modes so you don't have to use the headlamp for limiting current. You set the max current by shorting the leads and using the fine/coarse potentiometers to adjust it and when the current is limited the CC LED is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this all the time, make sure you put it on constant current. (the faster the better time but you can always trickle charge). I usually do somewhere around 13-14V and about 1A.
Make sure you have good cables, I had some bad chinese cables (bad alligator clips), I measured an 0.75V drop across them so a higher gauge wire (at least 18AWG) is desirable, the bigger and shorter the better. (or in my case I just raised the voltage a lot, but that can be dangerous if you leave)

I don't own a real car charger and usually just need to start my car, or if I'm working on my car I'll throw a lab supply on there.

I also charge SLA (sealed lead acid) batteries this way.

Answer (score 4):

Everything is great until you turn the power supply off with the battery attached... and the supply decides to self-destruct. Some lab power supplies - even a few made by respected brands - are infamous for being absolutely intolerant to back-feeding from low impedance sources such as lead-acid batteries.

I would **always add a fuse** between the power supply's output (say the positive one) and the battery. This will at least prevent the supply and/or wiring from catching fire should things go wrong. And the wiring will most definitely catch fire upon a short, since you're using wiring sized for a couple amps, whereas the battery can provide tens-hundreds of amps to a short circuit - vastly more than the power supply!

Comment: Why not a diode instead of a fuse?

Comment: @Coriolanus A fuse at the battery ensures that shorted wires anywhere, including shorts in the power supply or other malfunctions - such as shorted pass element in the supply - will blow the fuse and cause no further damage. A diode will dissipate more than a fuse, and it increases the output impedance of the supply. For lead acid charging should be no big deal - but if the supply has sense inputs, then those will in turn need to be fused.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flooded lead-acid, hook it up with 14.4v supply with even higher current. (Your car easily charges at 25 Amp). So, go ahead with 5 - 10Amps if your power supply can output. An advantage of trickle charging at 14.4V is, it will automatically balance out your cells. watch out for water level don't let it boil.
For AGM, do not overcharge.

Also, do it outdoors as it produces hydrogen and some hydrogen sulfide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 13.8 V at 1 A it will work fine provided your supply has a current-limited output. If the battery is very low, the charging current will start out high, so any overcurrent trip will operate. To knock up a current limiter, you can just connect a suitable load in series, say a hairdryer or a headlamp.

The main problem is the risk of overcharging, which will cause gas to form. This leads to issues of toxic fumes (vented battery), pressure buildup (sealed battery) and electrolyte loss.

So watch the amount of charge delivered (current x charge time = Ampere Hours or Ah, which is the unit of capacity for batteries). Once the battery is approaching capacity, reduce the supply voltage/current to reduce the risk of overcharging.